Old French map, mystery coordinate system in South America
I have this old map from a 1909 Atlas of Ecuador. This map was probably made in the late 19th century by a French Geodetic Commission (not the famous one from the 18th century!). Both latitude and longitude are off from a common WGS84 projection; as a reference, the city of Tulcan, in northern Ecuador, can be marked by a centroid at -77.71, 0.81. Thus, there is an offset of about 10 degrees at both latitude and longitude.
It is not the Paris coordinate reference system as this uses a meridian that is offset by 2.33 east of the Greenwich meridian, which only increases the offset with what should be a WGS84 projection.
There are no other notes on the map that I could recognize as proper references for a transformation to known coordinates.
Do you have any insights on this problem?


Hi, welcome to GIS.SE! Latitude can be measured without any reference with great precision (lot less than 10 degrees) since long time ago. Also, the scale shows that the grid is 10 kilometers, which is not one degree of latitude. So don't take the numbers as degrees, but kilometers (880, 890 kilometers west, 80, 90 kilometers north) from a grid center.

So long as you know approximately where this is, there is enough detail on the map to completely ignore the coordinate system and register it using known points in WGS84. If I was doing it, I would derive a stream coverage from SRTM and use stream intersections as control points but you also have a few well located place names.

@LeighBettenay Does the poster want to register the map (ie warp it to a known coordinate system) or do they specifically want answers about the system of coordinates used on the map?

I want to project it (register/warp) by georeferencing it on a GIS platform, so the ideas you give me are quite useful. Direct coordinates are always a plus though. Thank you!

I wonder if the measurements are French Revolutionary System angles, where a right angle was 100 "grads" (instead of 90 degrees) and then subdivisions of 100 centigrads, which are about a kilometre. This might explain the approx 10 "degree" offset and would also make sense with @GabrielDeLuca suggestion. Conversion to standard decimal degrees is fairly easy (divide by 100, mult by 90), then see where that gets you relative to the Paris meridian...

The coordinates seem to be French "decimal" angle measurements, from the Paris meridian.
The coordinates top-left of the map are 88:92:59. In the system, there are 100 grads in a right angle as opposed to our usual 90 degrees. So to convert, this angle is 0.889259 * 90 which is 80.03331. Include the -2.33 offset of the Paris meridian gives you 77.71 degrees, which is where the town is in WGS84 coordinates.
The lightbulb moment came when I noticed those coordinates had numbers bigger than 59 in the fractional part.
In small-scale mapping, ignoring the spherical earth, these coordinates are approximately metres because the system defined the metre as one ten-millionth of the distance from the equator to the north pole going through Paris. For more details, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_units_of_measurement#The_metric_system_restored_(1840%E2%80%931875)
The PROJ library supports different angular units, and it can work in these "gradians" (which is what they are, note the little superscript "g" on the map) so if you have the rest of the CRS parameters (exact Paris meridian and ellipsoid parameters) you could make a PROJ transformation from them to anything else. If you want to georeference the image it might be easier to map known features on the image since the scan isn't very rectangular (the bottom edge curls right up...).

Fantastic insight Sir! Thank you! It works wonderfully.

Not the answer per se, because didn't found a datum, however in: Mugnier C. J. 2023. Coordinate Systems of the World: Datums and Grids. CRC Press. DOI: 10.1201/9781003307785-58 you can read (p. 229):

The French mission to Quito to determine the length of a degree of
latitude (and to help settle the argument) started in 1735. The survey
was under the direction of Charles-Marie de la Condamine with Louis
Godin, and Pierre Bouguer of France. The Spanish representatives
included Capt. Jorge Juan y Santacilla, Captain Antonio de Ulloa
(later Governor of Louisiana), and Don Pedro Vicente Maldonado y
Sotomayor, a local gentleman of Riobamba. It took 10 years to
triangulate the 200 km meridional arc from Tarqui to Cotchesqui and
the French expedition proved that the Englishman’s theory was correct!
The survey is known as the French Mission Datum which found that a =
6,397,300 m and 1/f = 216.8. Another result of the observations was
the “toise of Peru,” a standard of linear measurement subsequently
used in France. Simón Bolívar later liberated South America from the
Spanish Crown, and Ecuador was established as a republic in 1830. No
further geodetic surveys were undertaken for almost 200 years after
the French Mission Datum was completed, and it was never later used
for mapping.

In Scientific American Supplement from 1903 you might find an article about The French Geodetic Mission to the Equator from ~ 1901 where lieutenant Perierr (author of your map) is mentioned.
Edit:
It seems, the results of the second mission were published in 10 volumes of Ministère de l'Instruction publique. Mission du service géographique de l'armée pour la mesure d'un arc de méridien équatorial en Amérique du Sud (see BNF catalog and vol 2 at archive.org with fantastic maps inside). Seems the calculation details are provided in vol. 3, however haven't found online copy.
Looking on the map coordinates --- looks like the original datum was around 11°50' East and 0°40' South, somewhere between Congo (French) and Equatorial Guinea datums, but none of them fit.

Fantastic documental research, although it does not provide the answer, I want to thank you for such great historical references.

Heh, I enjoyed it, honestly. Was intrigued and interested. There is another source about this survey: https://books.openedition.org/mnhn/2383 - I don't speak French, but seems it is based on relations of the Paul Rivet, the expedition doctor. If I may guess, the answer would be either in vol. 3 or vol. 1 of the Mission du service...  report. Let us know, if/when you find it :)
